# Mysql Query update multiple columns with multiple condition using WHEN, AND

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing sql UPDATE to 2 columns with 2 conditions. Before I run sql the sender_del_flag and receiver_del_flag are all 0 but after I run this some value return null. I wonder why it changed to null. How to fix this?

```
   UPDATE `messages` SET 
        receiver_del_flag = CASE 
            WHEN `id`='4' AND receiver='92' THEN '1' 
            WHEN `id`='6' AND receiver='92' THEN '1' 
            WHEN `id`='8' AND receiver='92' THEN '1' 
        END, 
        sender_del_flag = CASE 
            WHEN `id`='4' AND sender='92' THEN '1' 
            WHEN `id`='6' AND sender='92' THEN '1' 
            WHEN `id`='8' AND sender='92' THEN '1' 
        END 
    WHERE id IN ('4', '6', '8')
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This fixes the problem:

```
   UPDATE `messages` SET 
        receiver_del_flag = CASE 
            WHEN `id`='4' AND receiver='92' THEN '1' 
            WHEN `id`='6' AND receiver='92' THEN '1' 
            WHEN `id`='8' AND receiver='92' THEN '1' 
            ELSE receiver_del_flag
        END, 
        sender_del_flag = CASE 
            WHEN `id`='4' AND sender='92' THEN '1' 
            WHEN `id`='6' AND sender='92' THEN '1' 
            WHEN `id`='8' AND sender='92' THEN '1' 
            ELSE sender_del_flag
        END 
    WHERE id IN ('4', '6', '8');
```

Your `where` clause is getting rows where the `sender` and `receiver` are `92`.  These are set correctly.  It is also getting rows where the values are not `92`.  These are set to `NULL`, because there was no `ELSE` clause.

Comment: It will also be a more efficient if you add `AND (receiver='92' OR sender='92')` to the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Ok i see but i think i don't have to add that because its already in WHEN clause

Comment: @Khean . . . Barmar is saying that performance would be faster because on some rows, neither value is `'92'`.  There is no reason to attempt to update those rows.  In your sample data, this is rarely true, so this would be a minor optimization.  However, if `92` were in only 1% of the rows, then the improvement might be significant.

Comment: I see. But the result may come out differently. If you know another query that give the same result but better performance please post as an answer.

Comment: Oh sorry now i understand. If we don't add what @Barmar said it will go through all records as result it will be slow . i will modify my code now thanks you everyone